# Repeated Rules in Element's CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a client that has an existing blog through Squarespace. I am taking over the website, and am coming across some code I have never seen before. We have an issue with fonts rendering correctly across all browsers. When I inspect the elements in question, I find some very strange CSS code. I have noticed on many elements such as h1, that there are repeated rules in the CSS. See below for example:

```
#topNav nav, #topNav ul, #topNav li, #topNav a 
{
   font-family: Georgia,serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   font-size: 13px;
   text-transform: normal;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue","Arial","sans-serif";
   font-size: 30px;
   line-height: 4em;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   text-decoration: none;
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

As you can see, there are several repeated rules. What are the consequences of this CSS code? Could this cause the code to be styled differently on different browsers?

This is an extremely large website, so I am hoping this wasn't a habit of the last developer to code like this. Should cleaning the styles up be my top priority? Any opinions would be fantastic!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks this was made with a WYSIWYG. Only the last declaration of each property will be used

Comment: I can only imagine they tried out different styles, left the old ones in just in case they wanted to revert the canges, and then never cleaned it up. As far as I know, any browser will just discard the previous style if it finds a new one. The only reason to repeat basic styles like these is to provide a fallback when using units that older prowsers don't understand, but these are all in px and em.
Btw, the sans-serif should not be in quotes.

Comment: Normally the last rule will be applied, you can probably use browser web dev tools and inspect the element and copy/paste only the valid rules from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say that it is just poor coding. As for the impact on rendering, I would think that the last instance of the style would take precedence since the whole nature of CSS is "cascading" inheritance.

A simple experiment or two should yield the answer to your question.

Comment: So it really should not render differently in different browsers due to this poor coding issue I'm guessing. I am planning on cleaning the code, but fixing the cross browser issue is my top priority.

Comment: It's up to the specific browser as to how "forgiving" it is.  You might want to trying using a CSS Lint tool to help identify non-standard or cross browser issues.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I appreciate your time and knowledge.